# Remove data rows in dataframe if condition met

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have a dataframe of urls but I'm trying to remove rows that contains any image urls. I tried this but it doesn't work

```
url_pattern <- "http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\\(\\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+"
image_pattern <- "http[s]?://.*\\.(?:png|jpg)"

links <- str_extract(data[[2]], url_pattern)
images <- str_extract(data[[2]], image_pattern)

links <- links[!is.na(links)]
links <- data.frame(url = links)
links <- links[!url %in% images]
```

Comment: please provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, it seems you are overcomplicating things a little. Let's say you have the following `data.frame`:

```
df= data.frame(url = c('https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkCC0.png?s=48&g=1',
                       'https://www.google.com',
                       'https://www.this.is.an.image.jpg'),
                       id = c(1,2,3))

We can remove all rows that have an image URL in column `url` as follows:

image_pattern <- "http[s]?://.*\\.(?:png|jpg)"
df[!grepl(image_pattern,df$url),]
```

Result:

```
                     url id
2 https://www.google.com  2
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: wow cool! it works perfect! but is it able to apply when i dont have a data frame? like my links was a character vector. am i able to remove image urls from a character vector using grepl the same way?

Comment: Great. And yes definitely, if the vector is called `my_urls` you could do `my_urls[!grepl(image_pattern,my_urls)]`. So that's very similar.

Comment: Sweet! It works!! You're a genius. btw, I'm curious why there's a comma at the end in df[!grepl(image_pattern,df$url),]

Comment: That's because we want to keep all columns. For some more info about that, maybe see [here](https://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html)